# First time buyer unsure on which mortgage to go for

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, first-time-home-buyer

My husband and I are first time buyers are are looking at mortgage options but I'm unsure which option is preferable. We only have a 5% deposit so are being hit with not great interest rates.

Our mortgage advisor has said that the length of the mortgage won't affect the rate in our case, this would be 3.6% for a 2 year fixed mortgage or 3.8% for a 5 year fixed mortgage. For overpayment we would be capped at 10% of the outstanding mortgage value per year for the fixed term, then uncapped.

The questions are:

Is it best to go with a 2 year or 5 year fixed rate at the available percentages? I'm unsure whether fixing for 5 years at 3.8% is preferable to avoid interest rate rises, then potentially remortgaging after 5 years is best, or fixing for 2 years and remortgaging after that hoping to get a better rate due to higher LTV but risking interest rate rises sooner.

Also, is it best to go for a 20 year mortgage with a higher monthly repayment and less overpayment vs a 30 year mortgage with lower monthly repayment and more overpayment (we can afford the monthly repayment on the 20 year reasonably comfortably).

We would more than likely be living in the house for more than 5 years but would at some point down the line be looking to move/sell.

Comment: It is best not to go with any of them. Interest rates WILL raise and unless you can handle twice the interest rate - bad bad bad. Also, your question depends on your projection of future income - which you provide no information of.

Comment: @TomTom Are you saying no one should enter a mortgage contract except a full-term fixed mortgage (not widely available outside the US)?

Comment: @TomTom If our aim is to buy a house I'm unsure why the best advice is to not to take any of them, at the moment we are just ploughing money into rent. Your point about interest rates rising, would that indicate the fixed for 5 years would be preferable? I would say our joint projected income should rise gradually.

Comment: No, i mean you have to be prepared for interest rate to get up significantly in the next 5 - 10 year cycle. What good is buying a house if you can not afford that. YOu talk about the fixed 2 years - can you handle what comes after? Otherwise that is a fire sale coming. Btw., full term fixed.... got one of those over 20 years in germany, they are STANDARD here. But no, this is not about fixes - it is about you assiming yo ucan refinance lower when in reality we are at the bottom of a cycle.

Comment: Check the graph at https://www.propertyinvestmentproject.co.uk/property-statistics/uk-interest-rate-history-graph/ - This is not "it goes lower". And then research sub prime crises (US) for exactly the situation you enter in. The problem is not 2 or5 years - it is what you do in 7 years. If you CAN afford that - go for it, but if not - beware about that.

Comment: @TomTom: Your first comment is an answer, not a request for information or a suggestion to improve the question.  Put it in an answer and you can format it and we can vote on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think you can make the payments comfortably, even if interest rates rise (and they probably will), then over a 20 year mortgage you will pay a **lot** less interest.  If you're not sure, then take a 30 year one, and make overpayments whenever you can.

A 5-year fix gives you more certainty than you get from a 2-year one if interest rates are going to rise, if that's something that concerns you.

On the other hand, if you go for a 2 year fix, then you get the opportunity to make a large overpayment every 2 years.  Just let the fix run out (so the 10% cap doesn't apply any more), make a lump sum payment, then contact the lender for another 2 year fix.

It really depends on whether you expect to make overpayments, or if you just want to pay the mortgage every month with as much certainty as possible.

Comment: Going for the 30-year mortgage, but making payments as for the 20-year, ends up with the same interest payments, but with significantly increased flexibility.

Comment: It is very unlikely that first-time buyers are going to be able to overpay more than 10% per year.  If they could, they should probably wait six months and accumulate another 5% deposit (they will get a *significantly* better rate at 90% LTV).  Even if they can, by the end of five years they will have paid off half the mortgage.

Answer (score 3):

#### My Advice:

I would absolutely opt for the 2Y fixed, 30Y mortgage for the following reasons:

- The 30Y deal has lower contractual payments with a free option to overpay and permit greater capital repayments equivalent to the 20Y. It is unlikely you will exceed the 10% per year overpayment cap so this becomes effectively redundant.
- At the end of 2Y if the BoE hasn't hiked more than to around 1% (which is the current market forecast and already priced into those mortgage offers) then future mortgage rates are likely to be similar values to what you can currently achieve with the current 5Y fixed. However, you should be able to renegotiate a better rate at that point with lower LTV, without penalty. This is nice scenario to be in than having to wait a further 3Y for the fixed period to expire.

However, note that you should absolutely pay off as much capital as you can afford. There is no point cash sitting in your account when it could be reducing a 3.6% interest and working toward securing you better rates at the end of 2Y.

Additionally, from a risk management perspective you are comfortable with the payments then even if this did work out poorly and rates did rise unexpectedly higher than 1% in 2Y, since you are on the 30Y with lower payments you will be capable of weathering the storm.